# Close JButton in JFrame end program non-abruptly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, exit, jogl

What I am trying to do is make a button that will end the frame as well as end the program but allow other parts, JOGL in this case, to do their own dispose Functions.
For instance, when I use the standard close button for the JFrame with `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` it will end the program but allow JOGL to do its clean up. And if I do `System.exit(0)` it will not allow any clean up from JOGL.

Essentially:

Custom Close JButton ===> Cleanly end application.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `JFrame#dispose`?  Or using a `WindowListener` and monitor the `windowClosing` event to shutdown the other resources?

Comment: Jut have your close JButton call the clean-up routines then System.exit(0)...

Answer (score 1):

How about using WindowAdapter to override the WindowClosing event

```
 this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            //add your logic for closing here
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could free your resources in the button handler as Quirliom suggested.

But `System.exit()` is not as abruptly as you assume.

It calls all Shutdown hooks before ending the program.

To dispose your resources, you could add a shutdown hook for JOGL:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        animator.stop();
        frame.dispose();
    }
});
```

Tying your cleanup to a Button Handler or a Window is fine if you know all your exits. A shutdown hook makes sure your cleanup is called, however you exit your application.

Just make sure to keep your shutdown hook clean and simple.